# Dev Server and Live Server Can't Find Code Difference

Tags: php, linux, git, server

Recently I have taken over the maintenance of a commercial site. We develop it on a separate dev server and the live server is maintained by the customer. A couple days ago, I made a small change to one .php file to address some deprecated functionality (internal_encoding) as the version was upgraded to PHP 5.6 Everything worked well on the dev site and appeared to work well on the live site.

However, this morning, I discovered that some parts of the live site are not rendering properly. Since the dev is working as required, I have spent the last several hours trying to find the difference between the two. Now, the update I mention may just be a coincidence, and it is thoroughly possible that I am dealing with a separate issue.

If there is git installed and initialized on both servers, can I copy the code of the dev server to live easily? I am relatively new to Git, so a lot of terminology and advanced stuff is confusing to me. What is the best way to go about it?

P.S. I did the update to the live site using a folder mapped through SSHFS (simply edited the file in Aptana and it saved directly to the server). Could this have caused some unexpected file corruption?

Comment: Both, live and dev server are running the same PHP version? If git is installed on the server, it's probably using a deployment hook (post-receive), so just uploading/copying the files would work, but gets overwritten. So you need to push changes and checkout these from the server.

Comment: Since I am just taking over this project, I am still learning all the infrastructure. I discovered a couple days ago that the Live had a newer version of PHP. This newer version was causing some troubles in the Admin section that I meantioned above.

 Currently, the versions are the same on both sites.
So how would I do this? Push from dev to github and then pull from github to live? As I said, the words "hook" does not tell me much yet. Are you telling me that copying gets overwritten somehow? How?

Comment: I thought if git is installed on the server, there is a huge possibility that some kind of deployment script works there. Check the git directory on the server. Change to "hooks" directory. Is there a file named "post-receive"?